# Doesn't change variable

Tags: python, variables, typeerror, python-3.8

I am learning python and I am trying to make another calculator. When I try to run it the first few commands work but when I get to line 6 it says:
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`
The code is here:

```
if user_input==' squares':
    first_number=input(str(inp_words))
    second_number=input(str(sec_inp_words))
    f_num=str(first_number)
    s_num=str(second_number)
    answer=int(first_number)**int(second_number)
    print('the answer to '+str(f_num)+'to the power of'+str(s_num)+'is'+answer)
    print(str(words))
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: it should be `...+'is' + str(answer))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using a formatted string:

```
print(f'the answer to {f_num} to the power of {s_num} is {answer}.')
```

When you add an f or F before your string, the string is called a formatted string, like when you add .format() to the end of a string.

With formatted strings, you have less type converting to worry about.

In the curly braces, you can put any valid python expressions in them, like functions, because f-strings are evaluated at runtime.

Comment: +1 for appropriate code to solve the problem.  But consider more explanation than, "This should do it:".  For example, a sentence about the fairly recent f-string feature might be appropriate to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @AnnZen should solve your immediate problem (+1).  But you appear to have a larger problem dealing with `int` and `str` and remembering which variable is which:

```
second_number=input(str(sec_inp_words))
s_num=str(second_number)
answer=int(first_number)**int(second_number)
print('the answer to '+str(f_num)+'to the power of'+str(s_num)+'is'+answer)
```

As you're converting strings to strings multiple times!  One to get a better handle on this might be to include the variable type in the variable name:

```
inp_words_str = "Please enter the first number: "
sec_inp_words_str = "Please enter the second number: "
words_str = "Goodbye!"

# ...

if user_input_str == 'squares':
    first_number_str = input(inp_words_str)
    second_number_str = input(sec_inp_words_str)

    first_number_int = int(first_number_str)
    second_number_int = int(second_number_str)

    answer_int = first_number_int ** second_number_int

    print(f'The answer to {first_number_str} to the power of {second_number_str} is {answer_int}.')
    print(words_str)
```

This way you'll know not to call `str()` on  `*_str` variable and not to call `int()` on a `*_int()` variable, etc.  You also might consider using `float` instead of `int` in your calculator.